# Simple JSF p:fileUpload, multiple files

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, xhtml

im currently trying to create a small form for uploading multiple files using JSF.

At the moment im Using a p:fileUpload and its working fine with one file:

```
<p:fileUpload id="someID"   value="#{bean.file}" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xml)$/"
                        mode="simple"/>
```

When I change it to mode="advanced" and and create a Listener, which is filling my file-List it is working fine as well.
The problem is, that i still would like to have it looking like it has been before (with mode="simple") with having just a Button which starts the Filechooser but still is able to select multiple files (and handle them).
May be im just doing it wrong or is it impossible to upload multiple files using mode="simple"?

And yes I was searching before, tried several solutions but nothing was working for me.

Sorry for my bad spelling / grammer.

Greetings

Comment: Don't think you could achieve that with the standard file uploader. What you can do is, if you still want to keep the non-ajax uploader, to keep the files uploaded in a `@ViewScoped` bean, to save them all later. This won't allow the end user to select all of them at once in the FileChooser, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add more than one files using primefaces file upload. But you can have some other work around to add more than one files using primefaces upload.I have done this in my application.you need to store your files in temporary location Once you have added your file.finally you can show your files.if you need some examples i will send you.

**Thanks**

Comment: You mean you can't unless you use the `advanced` mode, don't you? `if you need some examples i will send you`: better post them here ;-)